# How to use a remote ssh output as an input into a scp

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have a list of systems and I want to copy a log file out of many logs files, to my local machine which has a specific date of logs.

```shell
for i in `cat serverlist`; do scp $i:$(grep -lR "2024-01-01 00:10" /opt/log/serverlog*) /tmp/logs/serverlog_$i;done
```

Comment: This question could use some more context.  I see the `scp` command, but which part of your post is supposed to be SSH output?  Does the command you posted not do what you were expecting?  Please explain what you were expecting.